# How to compare two dataframes in pyspark to find differences and highlighted them?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark

I want to compare two tables which are I extracted in CSV's formats. I am using pyspark, created dataframes for both the tables.
Requirement is two validate both the CSV tables and highlight different column values for all the columns.

1. Created first dataframe:
   df1 = spark.read.format("csv").option("header","true").load("abfss://abc@xyzxxxxxxx.dfs.core.windows.net/db2tables/source.csv")
   df1.show()
   df1.printSchema()

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/My4QB.png)

2. Created second dataframe:
   df2 = spark.read.format("csv").option("header","true").load("abfss://xyz@abcxxxxxxx.dfs.core.windows.net/db2tables/source.csv")
   df2.show()

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CADDu.png)

I would like the result to be like:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbqK2.png)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see a way other than to join the two data frames and to go over the new data frame column by column:

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import col, when

df = df1.alias('a').join(
  df2.alias('b'),
  on=[col('a.' + c) == col('b.' + c) for c in df1.columns],
  how="full_outer")

for column in df1.columns:
    df = df(
        column,
        when(
            col("a." + column) == col("b." + column),
            col("a." + column),
        ).otherwise("no match"),
    )

df = df.drop(
  *['b.' + c for c in df2.columns]
).select([col('a.' + c).alias(c) for c in df1.columns])
```

The last bit is there to get rid of all the extra column and the prefix that was added to avoid conflicts.

Good luck!

Comment: Yes I joined the tables however unable to highlight the differences , intention is show the difference in column values to the quality team,

Comment: Also I am getting "when" is not define in the above code.

Comment: it's imported from the same place that `col` is